# bind event on element before its fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, bind

I have a search results div that I want to be hidden if the user clicks anywhere outside of it. It is not a child of the search criteria div.
The problem I'm having is that .show() does not seem to be firing at all. I would have thought that the .hide() only fires after the initial click on the search button. Obviously when the search results div is closed I .unbind() the event.

Kinda stumped on this one so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's some sample code.

```
function search(){
    $('#criteria').bind('click',function(){$('#results').hide();});
    $('#results').show();
    $('#results').html('some html from ajax call');
}
```

---

```
<div id=criteria>
    <input id=criteria1 /><input id=criteria2 /><input id=criteria3 />
    <!-- a whole page of input elements and a ajax lookup -->
    <input type=text id=lookup /><input type="button" onclick="search()" value="search" />
</div>
<div id=results></div>
```

Comment: Try adding the hide-callback to something *bigger* like `body` or `document`.

Comment: @Yoshi but wouldn't that fire when I click within the results div? I need this to stay open so that multiple items can be selected.

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/WCLem/1/   hope it helps.

Comment: In your code example `show` is executed successfully, but in next moment `click` (that starts `seacrch()` function) is bubble-upped from `INPUT[type=button]` into `DIV#criteria`. As a result `DIV#criteria` `click` event is fired and hides #result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need something like this

```
<script>
$(document).bind('click',function(){$('#results').hide();});

function search(e){    
  $('#results').show();
  $('#results').html('some html from ajax call');
  e.cancelBubble = true;
}
</script>

<div id=criteria>
<input id=criteria1 /><input id=criteria2 /><input id=criteria3 />
<!-- a whole page of input elements and a ajax lookup -->
<input type=text id=lookup /><input type="button" onclick="search(event)" value="search" />
```

Comment: Nice! Just added in the .unbind so it's not firing when the results div is hidden;
    $(document).bind('click',function(){$('#results').hide();$(document).unbind('click');});